# Formatting .CSV in Powershell

Tags: powershell

So I'm writing a powershell script to help sort data I have, but I need that data in a certain format.

```
   FN:        ORG:     Title         Tel:      Email:
Example A     Exam A    Exa A        EX A       EA
Example B     Exam B    Exa B        Ex B       EB
```

However, the output I'm getting is:

```
FN:Example A
ORG:Exam A
Title:Exa A
Tel: EX A
Email: ExA
FN: Example B
ORG:Exam B
Title: Exa A
Email: EX B
```

What I wrote is:

```
> ls *.vcf|%{cat $_ >>"result.txt"}     Get-Content "result.txt" |
> Select-String -Pattern
> '(FN:)|(ORG:)|(TITLE:)|(TEL;WORK;VOICE:)|(EMAIL;)'>>new.csv
```

As I'm sure everyone can tell, I'm very new to this and trying to teach myself. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like the following:

```bash
Get-ChildItem *.vcf | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $oht = [ordered] @{} # Ordered helper hashtable
    # Find all lines of interest in the file at hand, split them into
    # field name and value, and add to the hashtable.
    $_ | 
      Select-String -Pattern '^(FN|ORG|TITLE|TEL;WORK;VOICE|EMAIL):(.*)' |
      ForEach-Object { $oht[$_.Matches[0].Groups[1]] = $_.Matches[0].Groups[2] }
    # Convert the hashtable to a custom object that Export-Csv understands
    # and output it.
    [pscustomobject] $oht 
  } |
  Export-Csv -Encoding utf8 new.csv # Adapt the encoding as needed.
```

Comment: worked perfectly! thank you so much! i really appreciate it

Comment: Apologies for not accepting in the first place! I had no idea what that checkmark was for! I figured upvoting would do that, but as a new user, I can't do that. Thank you for linking that discussion post. It'll be very helpful in figuring out how to conduct myself on this forum!

Comment: No worries, @DylanC - thank you for taking the time to read the discussion I linked to. My  impression, from many interactions here, is that the site simply doesn't provide enough guidance to newcomers, so I'm not surprised you didn't know what the checkmark is for.