# Hashtable to PSCustomObject issue

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Not sure where I am going wrong with this (technique taken from [Formatting .CSV in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72651356/formatting-csv-in-powershell)). 
Clothes.txt contains the following:

```
colour blue
size large
material velvet
label red
colour pink
size small
material cotton
label blue
colour green
size medium
material plastic
label purple
colour gold
size medium
material silk
```

I am using the following code to search clothes.txt for occurrences of the words: colour,size or material, and if found to add it as a key to a hashtable ($hash) with a value of the word that follows it in the list.

```
Set-Location d:\temp
Get-ChildItem .\clothes.txt |
ForEach-Object {
    $hash = [ordered] @{}
    $_ |
    Select-String -Pattern '(colour|size|material) (.*)' |
    ForEach-Object { $hash[$_.Matches[0].Groups[1]] = $_.Matches[0].Groups[2] }
    [PSCustomObject]$hash
}
```

when I enter $hash it appears to show me the correct data

```
PS D:\temp> $hash

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
colour                         blue                                                                                                                                                           
size                           large                                                                                                                                                          
material                       velvet                                                                                                                                                         
colour                         pink                                                                                                                                                           
size                           small                                                                                                                                                          
material                       cotton                                                                                                                                                         
colour                         green                                                                                                                                                          
size                           medium                                                                                                                                                         
material                       plastic                                                                                                                                                        
colour                         gold                                                                                                                                                           
size                           medium                                                                                                                                                         
material                       silk
```

However when I try to convert the hash table to a pscustomobject using `[pscustomobject]$hash` I get only one result

```
PS D:\temp> [pscustomobject]$hash

colour size   material
------ ----   --------
gold   medium silk
```

What I was expecting was all colours in $hash to be under the colour heading, all sizes under size etc instead of just the last entry.  I have tried all different approaches, loops, `getenumerator()` etc. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hashtables can't have duplicate keys, so `$hash[someExistingKey] = ...` will override the previous value. Objects can't have duplicate property names either, so your plan wasn't gonna work anyway :) Wouldn't you rather want 1 individual object per _set_ of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different way you could do it using [`Regex.Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-6.0):

```
[regex]::Matches((Get-Content .\test.txt -Raw), '(colour|size|material) (\w+)') | & {
    begin { $i = 0; $out = [ordered]@{} }
    process {
        $out[$_.Groups[1].Value] = $_.Groups[2].Value
        if($i++ -and $i % 3 -eq 0) {
            [pscustomobject] $out
            $out.Clear()
        }
    }
}
```

Using the example provided in question the output would be:

```
colour size   material
------ ----   --------
blue   large  velvet
pink   small  cotton
green  medium plastic
gold   medium silk
```